# Easy motion vim plugin mapping issue

Tags: vim, plugins

I have the vim EasyMotion plugin installed.

Pressing,

`<Leader><Leader>f` searches forward from the current line.
`<Leader><Leader>F` searches backward from the current line.

Is there a way to search the entire visible part of the buffer only using 'f'? I would ideally not want to use two different bindings for searching forwards and backward. One single binding to search the entire visible portion of the buffer would be most ideal.

Comment: EasyMotion's issue tracker is [over there](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion/issues).

Comment: Thanks for you very valuable comment. It was helpful. Truly was.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a mapping like this:

`nnoremap <leader><leader>f :execute "/\\%>" . line('w0') . "1\\%<" . line('w$') . "l"<left>`

That's a confusing syntax, so I'll unpack it.

`line('w0')` and `line('w$')` return the line numbers of the first and last visible lines in the buffer, respectively, so you use them to find the range for the visible part.

The `/` search command allows a range to be specified, but with an odd syntax. The format is `/\%>Xl\%<Yl` where X is the line to start from and Y is the line to end at.

It's not possible to just drop the results from `line()` into a normal `/` invocation, but we can build a string, using `.` to join segments together, and once the command is built, pass it in to `:exec` to make it happen.

Finally, there's the `<left>`. That's for cursor positioning. When you execute `<leader><leader>f`, the whole mapping fires as though you were typing it, so you end up with the full `:exec` command on the line, and it ends with a ", but you want to type inside those quotes. Alternatively, you could remove `"<left>` from the end of the mapping, but then you'll have to remember to close the quote after typing your search term.

I'm not familiar with EasyMotion, so this may not give you exactly what you were asking for (I realized this after I typed up the answer), but it will let you run a search in the currently visible part of a buffer only, and you can probably adapt it to EasyMotion's purposes without too much difficulty.